# Calculate highest occupancy over time period

Tags: javascript, database

Hi im doing a job at work where we have a camera system that pings everytime someone enters or exits a room so you would have data like this:

```
{enter:7, exit:6}
```

which should mean one person is left in room

I want to know what was the highest amount of people in the room over a given period lets just say 45 minutes. I could have 50 to 100 points of data how can i would out what the average would be

Thanks

// update with a code sample here

```
.then((results) => {
  // maybe a correct algorithim

  results.sort((a, b) => b.enter - a.enter);

  results.sort((a, b) => b.exit - a.exit);

  results.sort((a, b) => a.enter - b.enter || b.exit - a.exit);

  // results.sort(fieldSorter(["enter"]));
  let final_result = result.pop();

  console.log(final_result);
  if (final_result) {
    return parseInt(final_result.enter - final_result.exit);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
})
```

So before this code im gathering all the datapoints then try and sort them and pop off the highest entertence to the lowest exits but i think im going about this wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+average+over+time+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that enter time is always smaller than exit time (which contradicts your example data), the issue could be solved like this:

```
function getAverage(startTime, endTime, items) {
    let slots = {};
    for (let timeIndex = startTime; timeIndex <= endTime; timeIndex++) {
        slots[timeIndex] = 0;
    }
    for (item of items) {
        let enter = Math.min(item.enter, startTime);
        let exit = Math.min(item.exit, endTime);
        for (let momentIndex = enter; momentIndex <= exit; momentIndex++) {
            slots[momentIndex]++;
        }
    }
    let avg = 0;
    for (let slot of slots) avg += slot;
    return avg / slots.length;
}
```

EDIT

For computing the maximum you can do something like this:

```
function getAverage(startTime, endTime, items) {
    let slots = {};
    for (let timeIndex = startTime; timeIndex <= endTime; timeIndex++) {
        slots[timeIndex] = 0;
    }
    for (item of items) {
        let enter = Math.min(item.enter, startTime);
        let exit = Math.min(item.exit, endTime);
        for (let momentIndex = enter; momentIndex <= exit; momentIndex++) {
            slots[momentIndex]++;
        }
    }
    let max = 0;
    for (let slot of slots) max = Math.max(max, slot);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: this looks like a good answer but i realized i asked the wrong question i dont want average i want the highest amount of people over said period im going to edit question

Comment: @AviTeller edited my answer with the maximum computation. Note that only the last 3 lines changed, so, if you have multiple things to compute, then it might make sense to have an abstraction by passing a callback to the function and calling that, so the same logic could be reused without code duplication.

Comment: This looks good ive got real data to compare it against so ill see if it works thank you!